# Is it possible to evaluate $\lim_{n\to\infty}n(\sqrt[n]{4}-1)$ without applying L'Hospital's rule?

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

I can evaluate the limit with L'Hospital's rule:

$\lim_{n\to\infty}n(\sqrt[n]{4}-1)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\cfrac{(4^{\frac1n}-1)}{\dfrac1n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\cfrac{\dfrac{-1}{n^2}\times 4^{\frac1n}\times\ln4}{\dfrac{-1}{n^2}}=\ln4$

But is there any way to do it without using L'Hospital's rule?

Comment: The solution to this problem depends on the definition of logarithm. An easy route is to define the logarithm by $\log x=\lim_{n\to\infty} n(x^{1/n}-1)$ and then by definition your limit is $\log 4$. This definition of logarithm is equivalent to the one via integrals using Riemann sum so that is also taken care of. Please state your definition of logarithm.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If $f(x)=4^x$, then $f'(x)=\log(4)4^x$ and, in particular, $f'(0)=\log(4)$. In other words,$$\lim_{h\to0}\frac{4^h-1}h=\log(4)$$and therefore$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{4^{1/n}-1}{1/n}=\log(4),$$which is the same thing as asserting that$$\lim_{n\to\infty}n\left(\sqrt[n]4-1\right)=\log(4).$$Note that all that I used was the definition of derivative together with the knowledge of $(4^x)'$.

Answer (score 3):

You could try this.  As $n \to \infty$,
$$
4^{1/n} = \exp\left(\frac{\log 4}{n}\right)
= 1 + \frac{\log 4}{n} + O(1/n^2)
\\
4^{1/n}-1 = \frac{\log 4}{n} + O(1/n^2)
\\
n\left(4^{1/n}-1\right) = \log 4 + O(1/n)
\\
\lim_{n\to\infty} n\left(4^{1/n}-1\right) = \log 4
$$

Answer (score 2):

You could use a Maclaurin expansion for $e^x$:

$$\begin{align}
n\left(\sqrt[n]{4}-1\right)
&=n\left(e^{\ln(4)/n}-1\right)\\
&=n\left(\frac{\ln(4)}{n}+\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\ln(4)}{n}\right)^2+\cdots\right)\\
&=\ln(4)+\frac{1}{2}\frac{\ln(4)^2}{n}+\frac{1}{6}\frac{\ln(4)^3}{n^2}+\cdots\\
\end{align}$$

As $n\to\infty$, convince yourself that the trailing terms collectively converge to $0$, leaving $\ln(4)$.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach using known limit

> $$ \lim_{n \to +\infty} \frac{\mathrm{e}^{a_n}-1}{a_n} = 1 $$
> where $a_n$ is a sequence such that  $ \lim_{n \to +\infty} a_n = 0$.

$$
\begin{split}
\lim_{n \to +\infty} \frac{4^{\frac{1}{n}}-1}{\frac{1}{n}}&=\lim_{n \to +\infty} \frac{\mathrm{e}^{\frac{\ln 4}{n}}-1}{\frac{1}{n}}\\
&=\lim_{n \to +\infty} \frac{\mathrm{e}^{\frac{\ln 4}{n}}-1}{\frac{\ln 4}{n}}\cdot \frac{\frac{\ln 4}{n}}{\frac{1}{n}}\\
&=\lim_{n \to +\infty} \frac{\mathrm{e}^{\frac{\ln 4}{n}}-1}{\frac{\ln 4}{n}}\cdot \lim_{n \to +\infty}\frac{\frac{\ln 4}{n}}{\frac{1}{n}}\\
&=  1 \cdot \ln 4 = \ln 4
\end{split}
$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $t=\frac 1n \to 0$: $$\lim_{t\to 0} \frac{4^t-1}{t}  $$ which is of the well-known form $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{a^x-1}{x} =\ln a $.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a trick to prove convergence of the continuous limit$$
\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow\infty} x \left(\sqrt[x]4 - 1\right)
$$
if you know also know how to integrate $2^x$.
Observe:\begin{eqnarray}
x \left(\sqrt[x]4 - 1\right) = x \left(\sqrt[x]2 - 1\right)\left(\sqrt[x]2 + 1\right) = 2x\left(\sqrt[2x]4 - 1\right)\frac{\left(\sqrt[x]2 + 1\right)}{2}
\end{eqnarray}
Thus we get $$
x\left(\sqrt[x]4 - 1\right) = \frac{\sqrt[x]2 + 1}2 2x\left(\sqrt[2x]4-1\right) \frac{\sqrt[x]2 + 1}2 \frac{\sqrt[2x]2 + 1}{2} 4x\left(\sqrt[4x]4-1\right) = \left(\prod_{k=0}^{n-1} \frac{\sqrt[2^kx]2+1}{2}\right) 2^n x \left(\sqrt[2^n x]4 -1\right)
$$
Note that the multiplicands are always bigger than $1$, so this implies that $2^n x \left(\sqrt[2^nx]4 - 1\right)$ is decreasing in $n$, so the limit exists for each $x$. It's also pretty clear that the function $x\to x\left(\sqrt[x]4-1\right)$ doesn't have any oscillations in the limit, hence we have that the continuous limit converges, so we just have to compute it for one value of $x$, say $x=1$. Thus we have $$
\lim\limits_{z\rightarrow\infty} z \left(\sqrt[z]4-1\right) = \lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty} 2^n \left(\sqrt[2^n]4-1\right) = \lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{\sqrt[1]4-1}{\prod\limits_{k=0}^{n} \frac{\sqrt[2^k]2+1}{2}} = \frac2 {\prod\limits_{k=1}^\infty \frac{2^{1/2^k} + 1}{2}}
$$
Expanding the partial products, we can see that this product actually isn't hard to evaluate:\begin{eqnarray}
\prod_{k=1}^1 \frac{2^{\frac1{2^k}} + 1}{2} &=& \frac{2^\frac12 + 1}2\\
\prod_{k=1}^2 \frac{2^{\frac1{2^k}} + 1}{2} &=& \frac{2^\frac14 + 2^\frac12 + 2^\frac34 + 1}4\\
&\vdots&\\
\prod_{k=1}^N \frac{2^{\frac1{2^k}} + 1}{2} &=& \frac{2^\frac1{2^N} + 2^\frac{2}{2^N} + \cdots + 2^\frac{2^N-1}{2^N} + 2^\frac{2^N}{2^N}}{2^N}
\end{eqnarray}
The RHS is a left Riemann sum for $\int_0^1 2^t dt$ splitting the interval into $2^N$ subintervals. Thus we get $$
\prod_{k=1}^\infty \frac{2^{\frac1{2^k}} + 1}{2} = \int_0^1 2^t dt = \frac{2-1}{\ln 2} = \frac1{\ln 2}
$$
Hence we conclude $$
\lim\limits_{z\rightarrow\infty} z\left(\sqrt[z]4-1\right) = \frac{2}{1/\ln 2} = 2\ln 2 = \ln 4
$$